# How to use regex to exclude specific URLs from extension script

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

I want to run the chrome extension script for a URL that matches a specific Regex pattern, for example `/https:\/\/(?!en).*\.wikipedia\.org\/wiki/` which should match all wikipedia URLs that are not in English. However using the regex in my filter results in an error when loading the extension:

> Service worker registration failed
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Could not add listener

Here is the code I am using:

```
const filter = {
  url: [
    {
      urlMatches: "https://(?!en).*\.wikipedia\.org/wiki"
    }
  ]
}

chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener((details) => {
  console.info("test");
}, filter);
```

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "script.js"
  },
  "permissions": [
        "webNavigation"
  ]
}
```

I think there is something wrong with my regex (I do not get any error when providing a full URL), but I am not sure what.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Maybe you need to anchor the regex? `"^https://(?!en).*\.wikipedia\.org/wiki.*$"`. The example at the doc has anchors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/events/UrlFilter

Comment: I still get the same error with the anchors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems: the regexp should start with `^`, otherwise it'll match a maliciously crafted page with non-escaped section of a URL, `.*` should be `[^/]*` for the same reason, `\.` should be `\\.`, and most importantly **[RE2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) used by webNavigation API doesn't support look-ahead/behind** e.g. `?!`, so you can't use them.

You can check the URL inside the listener:

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(details => {
  if (details.url.startsWith('https://en.wikipedia.org/')) {
    return;
  }
  console.info('test');
}, {
  url: [{ hostSuffix: '.wikipedia.org', pathPrefix: '/wiki' }],
});
```

Alternatively, list all the languages explicitly in `urlMatches` like `"^https://(www|fr|be|ja)\\.wikipedia\\.org/wiki/"`